# Should my homepage's url contain the "home" keyword?

Tags: seo, url, canonical-url, homepage, path

I'm thinking about making an SEO improvement.  Which URL is better for my homepage?

- `http://example.com/home`
- `http://example.com/`

Since both URLs provide the same content, should I redirect `/home` to `/`, or redirect `/` to `/home`?

Comment: See also: [Home page keyword cannot be in the URL](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91148/home-page-keyword-cannot-be-in-the-url) and [Canonical URL for a home page and trailing slashes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31796/canonical-url-for-a-home-page-and-trailing-slashes)

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller. Why didn't u provide this as an answer? I would accept it as correct.

Comment: Did one of those answer your question?   They look related and possibly helpful to me.

Comment: I got to see them before posting my question, but your comment was more relevant in my case. Putting it all together was very enlightening.

Comment: Also, i saw someone recommending to look at amazon website and take it as example. For my surprise, the "home" keyword goes to a page with some house stuffs. This made clear to me that we should not use any keyword for the homepage.